# Grouping Data from Two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, `posts` and `posts_flags`. `posts` contains the rows of posts made by the users. Now, if some post gets reported, users have the ability to report the post, thus creating a flag in the `posts_flags` table. So basically, `posts_flags` can have multiple flags for the same post.

Now, what I'm trying to do is get the `posts` rows from the `posts` table and add a column to show which one has been flagged. To get that column, I am trying to do an INNER JOIN with `posts` and `posts_flags` using the `post_id`. However, I hit an issue now because the `posts_flags` can have multiple rows for the same post.

How can I get those data? Below is a sample structure of my tables and what I'm trying to achieve.

**posts table**

```
| post_id | post_title | post_body |
|    1    |   title a  | something |
|    2    |   title b  | something |
|    3    |   title c  | something |
```

**posts_flags table**

```
| post_id | user_id |
|    1    |   4     | 
|    1    |   5     | 
|    2    |   5     |
```

**What I am trying to achieve**

```
|  post_id | post_title | post_body | flagged
|    1     | title a    | something |   1
|    2     | title b    | something |   1
|    3     | title c    | something |   0
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why is the third row in the result post id = 2 instead of post id = 3?

Comment: @Barmar Oops. It was typo. I edited it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of joining with the whole table, join with a subquery that just returns 1 row per post ID.

It also needs to be a `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN`, so the result will have rows for the posts with no flags.

```
SELECT p.*, pf.post_id IS NOT NULL AS flagged
FROM posts AS p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT post_id
    FROM posts_flags) AS pf ON p.post_id = pf.post_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an inline subquery to check if the current post was ever flagged, like:

```
SELECT
    p.*,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM posts_flags pf WHERE pf.post_id = p.post_id
    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END flagged
FROM posts p
```

Or better yet:

```
SELECT
    p.*,
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM posts_flags pf WHERE pf.post_id = p.post_id) flagged
FROM posts p
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bEQ9fG4GMHTmB5jMsSmG9m/0)**:

```
| post_id | post_title | post_body | flagged |
| ------- | ---------- | --------- | ------- |
| 1       | title a    | something | 1       |
| 2       | title b    | something | 1       |
| 3       | title c    | something | 0       |
```

NB: for better performance, you want an index on `posts_flags(post_id)`.

Comment: I think this is the best solution.  With an index on `posts_flags(post_id)` it should have the best performance.  And, this was first so I don't know why it was not accepted.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: well, go figure... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Count the number of flags in a GROUP BY query, and check if the flag count is greater than zero:

```
select
  p.post_id,
  p.post_title,
  p.post_body,
  count(f.post_id) > 0 as flagged
from posts p
left join posts_flags f on f.post_id = p.post_id
group by p.post_id, p.post_title, p.post_body
```

You can also use

```
min(f.post_id) is not null as flagged
```

That might look confusing, but it avoids reading all flags for a post.